# rake db:migrate (error)!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Pranay-Tares-MacBook-Pro:music_library pranaytare$ rake db:migrate

(in /Users/pranaytare/Sites/music_library)
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I got this error while running rake in ROR.. plz help..
I recently installed mysql on my Mac and configured it.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Either install the gem as the error message says, or put the mysql gem in your Gemfile and run bundle install. In the Gemfile, it would be like :

```
gem 'mysql2'
```